# Derivative of matrix vector product

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus, jacobian

Assuming I have a vector $\mathbf{e} = \mathbf{Lx}$, with $\mathbf{e} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, $\mathbf{L} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^m$, and I want to take the derivative with respect to a third vector $\boldsymbol{\theta} \in \mathbb{R}^p$.

Both $\mathbf{L} = f(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ and $\mathbf{x} = f(\boldsymbol{\theta})$, so the derivative with application to the product rule is:

$$
\frac{d\mathbf{e}}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}} = \frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}} \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{L} \frac{d\mathbf{x}}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}.
$$

The jacobian $\frac{d\mathbf{x}}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times p}$ left multiplied with $\mathbf{L}$ results correctly in a $n \times p$ matrix for the final jacobian.

My question now is: what does $\frac{d\mathbf{L}}{d\boldsymbol{\theta}}$ look like. I found a some [posts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/150427/the-derivative-of-the-cholesky-factor/167719?noredirect=1#comment931731_167719) and [articles](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07527.pdf) that use the vectorization function
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(\mathbf{L}\right)}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}
$$

($\mathbf{A} = g(\boldsymbol{\theta})$ is an intermediary result that I use)

but I don't know what kind of tensor would have a form that can actually produce the correctly shaped jacobian of the final result $m \times p$. As far as I can see, the right multiplication of the vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 1}$ always produces a columns vector.

Comment: I am probably misreading the exercise but how is $\frac{dL}{d\theta}$ even defined? $\theta$ is not in the domain of $L$ unless $p=m.$ On the other hand, we have $f:\mathbb R^p\to \mathbb R^m:\theta\mapsto x(\theta);\ L:\mathbb R^m\to \mathbb R^n:x(\theta)\mapsto L(x(\theta))$ and $L$ is a linear transformation. Therefore, with $g:=L\circ f:\mathbb R^p\to \mathbb R^n$, the chain rule gives $g'(\theta)=L'(x(\theta))\circ x'(\theta)=L\circ x'(\theta),\ $ that is, if $h\in \mathbb R^p,$ then $g'(\theta)h=L(x'(\theta)h)\in \mathbb R^n$

Comment: ah sorry, I had a typo. I did'nt want to make it too complicated and give too many specifics about my problem because I thought they weren't relevant. Actually, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is an input parameter to a neural network $g$ and $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ is an intermediary result. $\mathbf{L} = cholesky(A) \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, such that $\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{L}\mathbf{L}^T$.

Comment: the jacobian $\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(\mathbf{L}\right)}{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}$ is the first part of the decomposition, but I want to chain it with $\frac{\mathrm{d}\operatorname{vech}\left(\mathbf{A}\right)}{\mathrm{d}\boldsymbol{\theta}}$, but I don't know how all those matrices look like.

Comment: The product rule you're using is only valid for scalars, not for vectors or matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to deal with tensors I recommend using some sort of index notation:

$$
\begin{align}
\left[\frac{\partial\mathbf e}{\partial\boldsymbol\theta}\right]_{ij} &= \frac{\partial e_i}{\partial\theta_j} \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\left[\mathbf{Lx}\right]_i \\
&= \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_j}\left(L_{ik}x_k\right) \\
&= \frac{\partial L_{ik}}{\partial\theta_j}x_k + L_{ik}\frac{\partial x_k}{\partial\theta_j}.
\end{align}
$$

(Note the convention that repeated indices imply summation.)

Comment: so in this notation, I am taking the derivative "row-wise". If I write this out, I get a sum of the different $e_i$ times the derivative of the corresponding row to $\theta$, which is the first summand of your last equation, correct?